# Comparing Struts 2 Iterator Objects with Spring Security Context

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security

Suppose that I am using the Struts 2 iterate tag on a list of objects. Each object has a property called creatorUserId.

I would like to compare the creatorUserId with the Id number of the currently logged in user.

How do I do this with Spring Security and Struts 2 in the JSP page?

`<security:authentication property="principal.userID" />` displays the current user's ID number

`<s:property value="creatorUserId" />` displays the current iterator item's creatorUserId.

I would like to do:

```
<s:if test="%{creatorUserId == <security:authentication property='principal.userID' />}">
```

but it is not a legal expression.

Can anyone help with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Struts, but `<security:authentication>` has a `var` attribute to export its result as a named context attribute:

```
<security:authentication var = "userId" property = "principal.userID" /> 
<c:if test = "%{creatorUserId == userId}">
```